# Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

hi all i am try to install Linux Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop with advanced option like here

[image]

and also i format my hard drive i was using windows before linux , when i had windows i have 3 partions one is c for windows folders and two partions for saving my folder (audio,images, etc) so after foramt my hard drive now i try to install linux ubuntu and this is first time to me using it i dont have any idea how can i split my hard drive or what is the best size for partions or what is the necessary partions or folder and their sizes for ubuntu i try to search but i cant understand very will
This photo i take it from google so this list is empty just 1 tb free so how can i partions my hard drive

[image]

also i dont understand what is the difference between "/" and "/home" and "/home/username"
And What is the best size for each one

In windows if i install a lot of programs i make c drive 150 gb or even 200 gb so where uhuntu save programs files

only me will use the laptop
i am software engineer so i install some ide and python packages

My laptop is 8Gb RAM
And 1Tb Hard drive

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot, or are you over-writing Windows? If you're overwriting Windows, I'd just accept Ubuntu's default partition scheme, at least until you learn more about the relevant considerations and can make your own call. Normally `/home/username` would have your personal files, documents, media, etc., and (the rest of) `/` would contain things like the actual programs, libraries, etc. `/home` is the parent folder that would also have, e.g. `/home/anotherusername` for someone else's files if there was someone else who used the same system.

Comment: For a 1tb drive, I'd give at most 200gb to `/` and give the rest to `/home`. 200gb is actually probably much more space for program files than even someone who likes to install a lot of programs is likely to need.

Comment: No i will use ubutn as a main os so i overwrite windows no dual

Comment: I see some answers make other patrions like swap and """ /boot """ and efi